# Creating Your Own Bazaar Server

Tags: server, repository, bazaar

I'm trying to run your own bazaar server on Ubuntu 12.04 server - so far after reading stuff in internet i found this "tutorial" http://michael.lustfield.net/content/creating-your-own-bazaar-server - this looked quite clearly for me so i have followed the instructions.

but at the end when i want to push something to repo i get only:

```
damian@damian-desktop:~/Pulpit$ bzr checkout bzr+ssh://testpxe.servebeer.com/home/tomasz/bzr/test1 testowy-projekt1
    bzr: ERROR: Permission denied: "/home/tomasz/bzr/test1/.bzr/branch-format": : [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/tomasz/bzr/test1/.bzr/branch-format'
damian@damian-desktop:~/Pulpit$
```

user permissions are ok - this was firs thing that i have checked (i have even tryed to give extremely generous permissions just for testing),

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you do have a user permission issue there.

The Bazaar branch on the server is in the home directory of user `tomasz`, but you seem to be doing the checkout as user `damien`. Does user `damien` really have permission to access the files of `tomasz`?

The blog article you linked does things differently. It puts the Bazaar branch outside of user home directories, in `/bazaar`, and sets up a dedicated group to access it, and makes all users part of that group.

In any case, I recommend a different approach, explained in Bazaar's documentation:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/admin-guide/simple-setups.html

In particular I recommend the section "Using a restricted SSH account to host multiple users and repositories". With that setup, each user can have their personal writable areas, and the *repository manager*'s area (maintainer of the trunk, often called the gatekeeper) read-only to other users. If you want all users to have write access to the trunk, you can do that too.

Comment: yes you're right, I am not doing exactly like in tutorial - i have adapted it to my needs. User Damian has all needed rights to read files. - i will try to set ut things as you recommended (i hope this will do the job :) )